# How to copy files from a docker image - dockerfile cmd

Tags: docker, dockerfile, mount

During build time, I want to copy a file from the image (from folder `/opt/myApp/myFile.xml`), to my host folder `/opt/temp`
In the Dockerfile, I'm using the --mount as follows, trying to mount to my local test folder:

`RUN --mount=target=/opt/temp,type=bind,source=test cp /opt/myApp/myFile.xml /opt/temp`

I'm building the image successfully, but the local `test` folder is empty
any ideas?

Comment: BTW when I print the destination folder, I can see the file there.

'RUN echo $(ls -1 /opt/temp)'

The issue is with the mounting. nothing is seen on the test folder on local host.

Comment: you've the COPY directives that you can use in Dockerfile. [#COPY-Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)

Comment: @vijay, The COPY instruction copies new files or directories from <src> and adds them to the filesystem of the **container** at the path <dest>. This question is the other way around: from the image to the host.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copying files from the image to the host at build-time is not supported.
This can easily be achieved during run-time using volumes.

However, if you really want to work-around this by all means, you can have a look in the [custom build outputs documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#custom-build-outputs), that introduced support for this kind of activity.

Here is a simple example inspired from the official documentation:

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM alpine AS stage-a
RUN mkdir -p /opt/temp/
RUN touch /opt/temp/file-created-at-build-time
RUN echo "Content added at build-time" > /opt/temp/file-created-at-build-time

FROM scratch as custom-exporter
COPY --from=stage-a /opt/temp/file-created-at-build-time .
```

For this to work, you need to launch the build command using these arguments:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --output out .
```

This will create on your host, aside the Dockerfile, a directory `out` with the file you need:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
└── out
    └── file-created-at-build-time
```

```
cat out/file-created-at-build-time 
Content added at build-time
```

Comment: now I notice that the Custom build output is instead of a Docker image. I need both, the image and the output file. Can this be achieved?

Comment: `docker build --target stage-a -t stage-a-image-name`. This will build only stage-a, will create an image from stage-a and skip stage custom-exporter. I don't think you can get both outputs in one shot.

Comment: is there a way to close/end the custom-exporter stage? I have more code after this stage, that must be applied in the end. I need the last part to be part of my image: `FROM alpine AS stage-a 
RUN mkdir -p /opt/temp/ 
RUN touch /opt/temp/file-created-at-build-time 
RUN echo "Content added at build-time" > /opt/temp/file-created-at-build-time 

FROM scratch as custom-exporter 
COPY --from=stage-a /opt/temp/file-created-at-build-time . CMD /bin/bash myscript.sh`